# Headphones and internal speakers suddenly broken Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 on a Sager laptop (or Clevo P750ZM). I'm not exactly sure what triggered it, but suddenly I have no sound output from either the internal laptop speakers or the headphone port. Strangely it does work through my monitors built-in speakers through the HDMI port. I followed all the troubleshooting steps found at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure. Here is the output of the script alsa-info.sh:

http://pastebin.com/9XZ7Kgt8

The only thing I can think of is that I put the laptop to sleep by shutting the lid right before I lost the sound, but I've done this before several times without a bad result.

The output of the second suggested set of commands that they give in the above troubleshooting link (step 4) is http://pastebin.com/wpy51BCu

BTW I dual boot with Windows on this laptop and the sound in Windows works fine through both the internal speakers and the headphone port

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

### First: Select correct output

Have you tried selecting a different output in Sound Settings? You can enter through the sound indicator, the settings menu or by searching for 'Sound' in the Unity Dash.

[image]

Here you can select the output for your sound. Just clicking the output will change were you will listen it from.

If you haven't done this then try it.

---

### Else: Reset User Configuration for PulseAudio

I would suggest deleting all user preferences as suggested [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=164868).

In terminal at your home directory (`~/`) enter this:

> rm ~/.pulse*
>
> rm ~/.config/pulse/*
>
> pulseaudio -k

The first to delete any specific configuration for your user and the last kills the server which restarts automatically.

---

### Or Else: DPKG-Reconfigure

In terminal run: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure pulseaudio`.

This resets the configuration to defaults and may fix your problem.

---

Hope this helps.